# Stacking multiple CSV using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to combine multiple CSV to single file.
My CSV contain multiple header and single column as shown below.
I am trying to bring it to single line using `pandas stack` and combine all the CSV to single file (which is shown in output). After `DataFrame stack` I am not able to transpose.

CSV-1

```
Meter   Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng
    mean    amax    amin    std mean    amax    amin    std mean    amax    amin    std
100 18770.48894 18796.39258 18740.99023 12.35456659 1.517610086 2.337940693 1.180871844 0.376509654 10528.66164 33711.04297 -37142.24609    17086.10914
101 18766.69757 18794.7793  18743.71289 12.34797672 4.016107898 5.77563715  2.859413862 0.885711033 -63622.61314    0   -168044.4219    43147.67343
102 18765.98531 18793.73242 18741.17383 12.32513131 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
103 18779.85341 18806.2168  18756.51563 12.65176057 12.59648324 16.88401031 9.394244194 2.025883062 -662463.0806    -465448.8125    -917255.75  122393.8565
```

CSV-2

```
Meter   Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng
    mean    amax    amin    std mean    amax    amin    std mean    amax    amin    std
100 32242.08167 32365.125   32144.06055 59.50414821 -145087.2668    -60506.76563    -228208.3438    43754.05571 227688.7283 286758.5625 169886.4844 29909.88285
101 32234.00285 32331.75195 32130.50586 56.32638996 -246840.9879    -194906.1875    -328136.2188    38632.09259 370574.4742 434396.9375 326996.625  28993.26708
103 32247.416   32343.55273 32142.01563 55.88355849 -265462.5869    -161577.5938    -417347.25  53775.36003 338769.1293 471060.8125 255875.2344 45288.34806
```

Output

```
FileName    100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103 100 101 102 103
    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Arng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Brng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng    Crng
    mean    mean    mean    mean    amax    amax    amax    amax    amin    amin    amin    amin    std std std std mean    mean    mean    mean    amax    amax    amax    amax    amin    amin    amin    amin    std std std std mean    mean    mean    mean    amax    amax    amax    amax    amin    amin    amin    amin    std std std std
CSV-1   18770.48894 18766.69757 18765.98531 18779.85341 18796.39258 18794.7793  18793.73242 18806.2168  18740.99023 18743.71289 18741.17383 18756.51563 12.35456659 12.34797672 12.32513131 12.65176057 1.517610086 4.016107898 0   12.59648324 2.337940693 5.77563715  0   16.88401031 1.180871844 2.859413862 0   9.394244194 0.376509654 0.885711033 0   2.025883062 10528.66164 -63622.61314    0   -662463.0806    33711.04297 0   0   -465448.8125    -37142.24609    -168044.4219    0   -917255.75  17086.10914 43147.67343 0   122393.8565
CSV-2   32242.08167 32234.00285 NaN 32247.416   32365.125   32331.75195 NaN 32343.55273 32144.06055 32130.50586 NaN 32142.01563 59.50414821 56.32638996 NaN 55.88355849 -145087.2668    -246840.9879    NaN -265462.5869    -60506.76563    -194906.1875    NaN -161577.5938    -228208.3438    -328136.2188    NaN -417347.25  43754.05571 38632.09259 NaN 53775.36003 227688.7283 370574.4742 NaN 338769.1293 286758.5625 434396.9375 NaN 471060.8125 169886.4844 326996.625  NaN 255875.2344 29909.88285 28993.26708 NaN 45288.34806
```

My Code

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = r"D:\Test"
files = os.listdir(path)
csvFile = [fil for fil in files if fil.endswith('.csv')] 

for efil in csvFile:
    #Read CSV
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,efil), header=[0,1], index_col = 0)
    #stack dataframe
    stackeddf = df.stack([0, 1])
    #Transpose
    print(stackeddf.T) # I am stuck here
    #merge stacked CSV

    #Re-align the column header
```

Comment: if files are of the same structure, you could append them to an empty list, and then use `pd.concat` to merge.

Comment: Some times the meter might be missing, Comparing to CSV-1, meter 102 is missing in CSV-2.